# Azure Cognitive Services - Form Recognizer (preview) - Not able to select location

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I'm trying to create a Form recogniser solution for a use case and got approval for preview. But I'm not able to select the location while creating my resource from Azure Portal[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xvbr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Form Recognizer is currently available in West US 2 and West Europe locations only, with regional availability expanding in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are signed into the Azure Portal with the same subscription ID provided in the access request form. If you have several subscription IDs please use switch directory in the portal to switch to the whitelisted subscription.